# Получение класса Fragmenta?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Бойня продолжается, задал два вопроса что бы понять как сформулировать свою проблему.

Есть три фрагмента

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
    TextView textView;




    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.artist_fragment,null);
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        return v;
    }


    public void setTextTextView(String text){
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Код других frag2 и frag3 одинаков.

Прикручиваю viewerPager:
Adapter:

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    static final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

    Frag1 frag1 = new Frag1();
    Frag2 frag2 = new Frag2();
    Frag3 frag3 = new Frag3();



    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position==0) return frag1; else
        if (position==1) return frag2; else
            return frag3;

    }




    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (position==0) return  "Об  Артисте"; else
        if (position==1) return  "Альбомы"; else
        if (position==2) return  "Песни"; else
            return "Title " + position;
    }

}
```

MainActivity on create

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
        PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pagerTabStrip);
        pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        Frag1 frag11 = (Frag1)pagerAdapter.getItem(0);
        frag1.setTextTextView("Любой текст");
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {


            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected, position = " + position);
                //Fragment fragment = pagerAdapter.getItem(position);
                //if (fragment instanceof  Frag1){
                 //  frag1 = (Frag1) fragment;
                //    frag1.setTextTextView("string");
               // }

                Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected, position = " + position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                                       int positionOffsetPixels) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected, position = " + position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected, position = " + position);
            }
        });
```

Вопрос вот в чем, если убираем строчки

```
Frag1 frag11 = (Frag1)pagerAdapter.getItem(0);
        frag1.setTextTextView("Любой текст");
```

То подгружаются все фрагменты, и работает нормально. Но мне нужно, вот что, когда создается Активити, я получаю данные с сервера, и отправляю их во фрагмент (frag1.setTextTextView("Любой текст");). Но он у меня Null и ни что не могу с этим поделать!

Comment: Не в тему, но что значит "код других фрагментов одинаков"? Совсем одинаков?

Comment: ну структура похожа, изменений только в имени класса!

Comment: почему бы не оставить один класс и просто не создать три экземпляра этого класса?

Comment: Так не пойдет, в будущем все фрагменты будут иметь разные внутренности!

Comment: Frag1 frag11 = (Frag1)pagerAdapter.getItem(0);
frag1.setTextTextView("Любой текст"); Я надеюсь, это описка? Или в коде так? Разные имена у фрагментов.

Comment: Соберите минимальный проект где воспроизводится проблема и выложите в архиве - я гляну.

Comment: Решил проблему через newInstance и аргументы